# finding maximum of a function

Tags: calculus

Need help in finding maximum of the following function: $1-\sum_{i=1}^{n}p_i\times \frac{p_i-1}{log(p_i)}$ given that $\sum_{i=1}^{n}p_i=1$.

Thank you for your time and help.

Comment: Where does it come from -- is it a homework, something else ? What did you try so far?

Comment: No, it has nothing to do with homework, I am doing a project on entropy (shannon), and I want to know the max of this function, could you please help me at your earliest convenience? I really need to know it soon.

Comment: Are the $p_i$'s non-negative?

Answer (score 0):

(hopefully correct, didn't have time to check carefully)

- **Lower bound:**

You want to bound $\mathbb{E}_{x\sim p}[\varphi(p(x))]$, where $p$ is the distribution on $\{1,\dots,n\}$ defined by $p(i)=p_i$ and $\varphi\colon t\mapsto \frac{t-1}{\log_2(t)}$. Note that

- $\varphi$ is continuous on $[0,1]$, with $\varphi(1)=\ln 2$ defined by continuity (as $\lim_{t\to 1^-} \varphi(t)=\ln 2$);
- $\varphi$ is concave.

Now, apply Jensen's Inequality to get
$$
  \mathbb{E}_{x\sim p}[\varphi(p(x))] \leq \varphi\left(\mathbb{E}_{x\sim p}[p(x)]\right) = \varphi\left(\sum_{i=1}^n p_i^2\right).
$$
You can get an upper bound on $\sum_{i=1}^n p_i^2$, e.g. $\max_i p_i$ for instance. Or $1$ for the trivial upper bound $\sum_{i=1}^n p_i^2 \leq \sum_{i=1}^n p_i = 1$. For the latter, you get
$$
  \mathbb{E}_{x\sim p}[\varphi(p(x))] \leq \varphi(1)= \ln 2.
$$
Note that this is achieved for $p_1=1$, $p_i = 0$ $\forall i > 1$. The minimum of your function is then $1-\ln 2\simeq 0.307$

- **Upper bound: (what you want)**
  Rewrite the expression as $1+\sum_{i=1}^n \frac{p_i(1-p_i)}{\log_2(1/p_i)}$. $\psi\colon t\mapsto \frac{t(1-t)}{\log_2(1/t)}$ is concave, and you want to maximize it. I haven't time to continue right now, but I would wager the maximum (via some convexity argument) is obtained when all $p_i$'s are equal to $1/n$, in which case you get
  $$
  1 + \frac{1-1/n}{\log_2 n}.
  $$